# Upload multiplos arquivos no mesmo form e gravar nome no banco

Tags: php, mysqli, input, file-upload

Tenho um form de cadastro com dois input de arquivo.

Um chamado arquivo (uma imagem) e outro chamado arquivo_download(um pdf).

Na minha tabela tenho uma coluna [imagem] e outra [downloads], que gravam o nome do arquivo e sua extensão, para ser usado em exibições e link de download.

Tenho o código.

```
<?php
        include_once("../../conexao/conexao.php");
        $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']);
        $texto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['texto']);
        $situacao_downloads_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['situacao_downloads_id']);
        $situacao_downloads_ordem = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['situacao_downloads_ordem']);

        //Pasta onde o arquivo vai se salvo
        $_UP['pasta'] = '../../../imagens/downloads/';

        //Tamanho máximo do arquivo em Bytes
        $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*1024*100; //5mb

        //Array com as extensões permitido
        $_UP['extensoes'] = array('.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.pdf');

        //Renomeia o arquivo? (se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e em nome único)
        $_UP['renomeia'] = false;

        //Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
        $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
        $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o limite do PHP';
        $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especificado no HTML';
        $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
        $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito enviado de nenhuma imagem';

        //Verfica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe mensagem de erro
        if($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0){
            die("Não foi possivel fazer o upload, erro: <br>". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
            exit; //para a execução do script
        }

        //O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar move-lo para a pasta foto
        else{
            //Verificar se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
            if($_UP['renomeia'] == true){
                //Criar um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com a extensão jpg
                $nome_final = time();
            }else{
                //Mantem o nome original do arquivo
                $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
            }
            //Verificar se é possivel mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'].$nome_final)){


                //Upload efetuado com sucesso
                $result_downloads = "INSERT INTO downloads (ordem, nome, texto, situacao_downloads_id, imagem, downloads, created) VALUES ('{$situacao_downloads_ordem}','{$nome}', '{$texto}', '{$situacao_downloads_id}', '{$nome_final}', '{$nome_final_arquivo}', NOW())";
                $resultado_downloads = mysqli_query($conn, $result_downloads);
                if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0){
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=".$dominioadm."administrativo.php?link=24'>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"SUCESSO! Download foi cadastrado com sucesso.\");
                    </script>
                ";  
                }else{
                    echo "
                        <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=".$dominioadm."administrativo.php?link=23'>
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"ERRO! Não foi possivel cadastrar o download, tente novamente!\");
                        </script>
                    ";  
                }
            }else{
                //Upload não foi efetuado com sucesso
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=".$dominioadm."administrativo.php?link=23
                    '>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Erro! dica não foi cadastrada. Erro no upload do arquivo, verifique o tamanho do arquivo 2 megabytes ou formato png, jpg, jpeg, gif.\");
                    </script>
                ";
            }
        } ?>

<?php $conn->close(); ?>
```

Estou tentando usar o [move_upload_file], para fazer o upload dos 2 arquivos na mesma pasta, pois são 2 arquivos diferentes, um a imagem do produto, e outro o arquivo pdf do catalogo do produto.

E um inset, que pega os nomes dos arquivos e grava nas suas colunas.

Mas somente consigo enviar um arquivo de cada vez.

Alguém puder ajudar, ou me guiar de como fazer.

Comment: Em que parte do código você chama a função `move_uploaded_file` para `arquivo_download` e o que seria esse `$_FILES["arquivo, download"]`?

Comment: Parece que você está fazendo uma confusão entre PHP e seletores de DOM (CSS, JavaScript) ao utilizar esse código `$_FILES["arquivo, download"]`

Comment: Eu editei o código para original, essas duas linhas são tentativas minhas, como não compreendi, acabei deixando no código, desta forma faz somente o upload e grava no banco o do arquivo que vem do input "arquivo", já o arquivo downloads que vem do input "downloads" não acontece nada porque falta no código. Isso:  `move_uploaded_file para arquivo_download e o que seria esse $_FILES["arquivo, download"]` e `$_FILES["arquivo, download"]`, não existem foram tentativas.